# How is omega 3 deficiency determined?

Tags: lipids

I read quite a bit online about omega 3 deficiency. How is this actually determined - that is, what happens in the lab to determine this ?
n-3 fatty acids have roles in many different human tissues, so does the definition of sufficiency vary depending upon which tissue is being studied ?